MongoDB aggregation - multiple levels of expanded product categories
I'm using the ecommerce platform swell, which allows for aggregation queries. I have to return product data with multiple levels of expanded categories.
the products have a category_index.id field that is an array of category IDs. What I need to do is to get all the categories returns into a "categories" array field, but then also get multiple levels of expanded category parents.
So the product data starts like this:


// product data

{
  _id: 'xxx',
  category_index: {
    id: ['123','456','789']
  }
}

// category data
{
  _id: 'xxxx',
  'parent_id': 'xxx' // categories can be several levels deep
}



I've got a start on the aggregation that returns some of what I'm looking for:
export const getProductBySlug = async (slug: string) => {
    const product = await swell.get('/products', {
        aggregate: [
            {
                $match: {
                    slug
                }
            },
            {
                $lookup: {
                    from: 'com.categories',
                    localField: 'category_index.id',
                    foreignField: '_id',
                    as: 'categories'
                }
            },
            {
                $lookup: {
                    from: 'com.categories',
                    localField: 'categories.parent_id',
                    foreignField: '_id',
                    as: 'categories.parent'
                }
            }
        ]
    })


the problem with this is that it just returns the category parents into a separate field, instead of nested into each category.
this is the format I'm looking looking for:


{
  /* product data */
  id: 'xxx',
  name: 'productName',
  slug: 'product-slug',
  categories: [{
    /* category data */
    parent: {
      /* category data */
      parent: {
        /* category data */ }
    }
  }]
}




Have you checked out $graphLookup for recursive lookup?

ray: $graphLookup still returns a flat structure. Hit this wall few years ago https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73845955/mongodb-aggregation-how-to-model-a-collection-to-return-a-tree-structure   chuckieDub: please check if any advices from there could be applicable in your case.

@AlexBlex recursive structure is generally considered as anti-pattern and I don't want to encourage it at first place. There is an existing solution to build it but I prefer to wait for OP's confirmation before voting to close as duplicate

@ray, thanks for the link. Tree structures can be very handy and massively reduce computation cost in many cases, e.g. binary trees, decision making, even html is a recursive tree. It would be great to learn when they are considered an anti-pattern tho.

@AlexBlex sorry I made the previous statement confusing. What I really meant is the dynamic level of recursive structure will cause unnecessary query complexity and potentially exceed the 16MB document limit. Although it is not listed as one of the official anti-patterns, it still share a lot of symptoms with Unbounded Arrays and Bloated Documents.
